# How can I compare stats of transistors?

Tags: transistors

For a project that I am doing, I need an FQP30N06 MOSFET, but I only have SS8550's and S8050's. The charts that show their stats weren't showing much that was the same on either chart, I'm also new to electrical engineering stuff. Is there an easy way I can compare them?

Also, if anyone knows if either of the transistors I have can be used instead of the MOSFET, please let me know.

Comment: BJT's and MOSFET's are different beasts entirely. So no, not a good idea.

Comment: Replacing X with Y (even if Y is a different beast to X) requires analysis of the target circuit and not necessarily an analysis of the data sheets (not that you have provided any links to the data sheets anyway).

Comment: The working behavior of bjts and mosfets are very different. You can’t easily compare them and you can’t easily swap them

Comment: If you need an FQP30N06, it might be prudent to buy a few now while they are still available, e.g. Farnell UK have >500 in stock, but the next batch won't be available until June 2022.

Comment: To compare the "curves" of operation, a [curve tracer](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=curve+tracer&t=opera&ia=web) could be used.  No BJT will match a MOSFET, so you do have to be in the same family of component.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the FQP30N06 is a 30A 60V MOSFET capable of dissipating tens of watts safely given a proper heatsink, and the transistors you have are 25V TO-92 transistors comfortably capable of switching hundreds of mA, and dissipating some hundreds of mW.

The circuits required for switching would be a bit different (because they are different kinds of devices) and  you could only substitute the SS8050 if the load was very light in comparison to what the FQP30N06 is capable of.